# Fail to install FlexGen: ImportError: cannot import name 'define' from 'attr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chatbot

I am trying to install [FlexGen](https://github.com/FMInference/FlexGen#install) on Ubuntu running under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL; but not WSL2). I have already installed a required PyTorch >= 1.12 and run `python3 -m flexgen.flex_opt --model facebook/opt-1.3b`, but an error message `ImportError: cannot import name 'define' from 'attr'` comes out and FlexGen is unavailable in my environment. Actually, `attr.py` does not have `define` package. Then, what should I do to solve this issue?

```bash
$ python3 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
1.13.1+cu117

$ python3 -m flexgen.flex_opt --model facebook/opt-1.3b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/MY_USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flexgen/flex_opt.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flexgen.compression import CompressionConfig
  File "/home/MY_USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flexgen/compression.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flexgen.pytorch_backend import (TorchTensor, TorchDevice,
  File "/home/MY_USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flexgen/pytorch_backend.py", line 16, in <module>
    from flexgen.utils import (GB, T, cpu_mem_stats, vector_gather,
  File "/home/MY_USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flexgen/utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from attr import define, field
ImportError: cannot import name 'define' from 'attr' (/home/MY_USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should install "attrs", not "attr".

```
pip uninstall attr
pip install attrs
```

Comment: import requests_cache  ImportError: cannot import name 'define' from 'attr'